# what is the index in the following function?

Tags: android, stagefright, openmax

```
sp<MetaData> MP3Extractor::getTrackMetaData(size_t index, uint32_t flags) {
    ALOGE("%s\t%d",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);

    if (mInitCheck != OK || index != 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return mMeta;
}
```

Why this function is required in the `MP3Extractor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MediaExtractor` is a module that implements container or file-format parsing of a multiplexed data. In a file there will be multiple `track`s which correspond to specific data like `video` or `audio`. Similarly, in a `MP3` file, there could be multiple tracks which are identified by their index. The index in the function corresponds to a specific `track` of interest.

Now, why is this function required? Since `MP3Extractor` is another extractor in the framework, it has to support this function, the reason for which follows. Let's consider the `player` as an example. `AwesomePlayer` is a player engine which sets up the entire pipeline.

In this process, the player engine would setup the extractor first and then try to create a down-stream component like a `decoder` to consume the data. The `decoder` is specific to a track which is identified by the `index`. To create a `decoder`, one requires to know the characteristics of the data which is represented or captured in `meta` i.e. metadata which will be employed to create and initialize the down-stream component.

Comment: @wn.. to some extent..how can I help you?